Export spreadsheet curve data
I have a bezier curve and wanted to calculate the length of all the possible segments in the curve (distance between points at index 0 and index n for all points). The easiest way I was able to accomplish this was using Spline Parameter in GN (see setup below). I want to now export this data to csv or even print to console but can't seem to find a way to do it. There are multiple answers here on doing this using python for meshes but they don't seem to work in my case. If there is a way to calculate the length of all possible segments in some other way (like using python) then I am open to exploring that as well.

